# xpath to extract first href in class

Tags: javascript, html, xpath

Let's assume I have html

```html
<div class='test'>
  <div class='_test_'>
    <a class='test1 href='/page-1'> Press here! </a>
  </div>
  <a href='/page-2'> Or here </a>
</div>
<div class='test'>
  <a href='/page-6'> Another href </a>
</div>
```

What xpath shall I use for getting only first  href value in class='test'?
Wanted result is an array: [/page-1, /page-6]

Comment: Show us your tried code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**One possible XPath :**

```
//div[@class='test']/descendant::*[@href][1]/@href
```

**<kbd>[`demo`](http://xpatheval.apphb.com/LiO56S2a4)</kbd>**

**brief explanation :**

- **`//div[@class='test']`**: find `div` element where `class` attribute value equals 'test'
- **`/descendant::*[@href][1]`**: within such `div`, find any element that contains attribute `href`, and then restrict the result to only the first of such element
- **`/@href`**: from previously found element, returns `href` attribute